# My own IPv6 tunnel

Tags: linux, ipv6, tunneling

I have a load of IPv6 addresses on my VPS which are not tunneled they are provided by the VPS host. But my ISP at home BT, has no plans yet to allocate IPv6 addresses to even business customers. I don't want to use a tunnel broker that gives me a dynamic IPv6, I want to be able to tunnel into my VPS and assign one of its IPv6 addresses to my home computer. BTW i'm all ubuntu linux.

Comment: "a load of IPv6 addresses" is way too vague. You must at least specify if it is a /64 or bigger allocation. This changes everything.

Comment: Why not use a tunnel broker that gives you a permanent address?  Using tunnelbroker or sixxs you can get a permanent tunnel that will have a permanent /48 or /64.

Answer (score 1):

A high level answer ...

You will have to setup a 6to4 tunnel from your home computer to your VPS.  One of the machines in your VPS will have to act as the tunnel endpoint.

Your home computer will need a public routable IPv4 address.  One of your VPS machines will need a public routable IPv4 address.

You will then setup a tunnel, setup routes between the tunnels, setup router-advertisements or manually setup your local IP's.  Lots up manual networking.

To me, it would seem simpler to setup a permanent tunnel to one of the tunnel brokers.  This way you only have to configure your side of the tunnel which is very well documented.